# How do I transfer files from my Steam Deck to a PC without leaving gaming mode?

Tags: networking, steam-deck, steam-os

I have various screenshots and emulator save files on my Steam Deck that I want to transfer to my desktop. My current solution is to use [Warpinator](https://steamdeckhq.com/tips-and-guides/warpinator-wireless-transfer-from-windows/), but it requires me to close the game I'm playing and exit to desktop mode whenever I want to transfer files, which is a bit cumbersome. I've also tried [uploading screenshots through Steam](https://www.pocket-lint.com/gadgets/news/steam/163923-how-to-screenshots-on-your-steam-deck-and-access-them-remotely/#:%7E:text=To%20do%20that%20press%20the,a%20button%20to%20select%20it.&text=Select%20that%20option%20and%20you,privately%20to%20your%20Steam%20account.) to transfer them, but this doesn't work for non-steam games.

How can I transfer files from my Steam Deck to a PC without having to switch from Gaming Mode to Desktop Mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using terminal, you can spin up ssh server on Steam Deck and access it with any of dozens compatible tools, for example, command line [scp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) which is now available even on Windows.

**Enable SSH server:**

- on your Steam Deck go to Desktop mode, open Konsole app, which is built-in terminal;
- for the next step you need to have "sudo" permissions, which will require you to set up a password for default account (`deck` usually), so configure it if you haven't already;
- run `sudo systemctl enable sshd` to enable ssh server on start and you can run `sudo systemctl start sshd` to start it right now;
- you can now return to gaming mode.

**Browse files**

Then on your other machine you can connect to Steam Deck even when it's in Game Mode. I'm on Mac, so I already have `scp` and `ssh` pre-installed. I can use `ssh` to connect to Steam Deck and browse files:

```
 ssh deck@steamdeck.local
deck@steamdeck.local's password:
Last login: Wed Feb 21 14:06:30 2024 from 192.168.0.106
(deck@steamdeck ~)$ cd GD_Saves_Backup/
(deck@steamdeck GD_Saves_Backup)$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 10 deck deck 4096 Jun 19  2023 .
drwx------ 43 deck deck 4096 Feb 21 14:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 deck deck 4096 Jun 15  2023 save_14_jun_2023
...
```

where `deck@steamdeck.local` is in `user @ hostname` format. If for some reason `steamdeck.local` is not resolved, you will have to find your local network ip address assigned to Steam Deck and use it instead. You will also have to provide user password, it's the same password used with `sudo` before.

**Copy**

Then once I know what I want to copy, I'm using `scp` to copy files over:

```
 scp -r deck@steamdeck.local:/home/deck/.local/share/Steam/userdata/111238817/760/remote/739630/screenshots .
deck@steamdeck.local's password:
20230430224004_1.jpg                                                                                                                                                      100%  533KB 611.9KB/s   00:00
20230419235222_1.jpg                                                                                                                                                      100%  756KB   2.0MB/s   00:00
...
```

Here command's format is `scp SOURCE DESTINATION`, source is on remote machine, so I have to provide user and hostname for it. Then regular folder path is added. Destination is on local and I use `.` to copy into the current folder. `-r` is recursive flag, I need it to copy entire folder instead of individual file.